# Connect database from sql server in angularjs using php

Tags: php, angularjs, database

I am trying to create a website in angularjs. Want to connect database from sql server using php. I am using IIS for the same. Can anyone please help me with the process for the same.

Thank You

Comment: Can you please brief the question. Do u want to connect to database from angular or you want to know how to connect to a database and get some data from php using angular?

Comment: @rahulpatel I am creating a travel management site, i am creating a database for the same in microsoft sql server management studio. So, now I need to get the data from there to my site, how that can be achieved? Mention ur suggestions or process for the same.